# Process in c# freezes up

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd, ffmpeg

environment: Rider 2022.1.2, .NET 6.0, Windows 10

The following piece of code should copy the musicFile that is given and add a cover to the copy, then place it as name: `title - artist.extension` in the same directory, for example `never gonna give you up - rick astley.mp3`

When debugging, if i copy-paste what is saved in the variable `p.StartInfo.Arguments`in a CMD terminal, it works perfectly, but in my c# code the program freezes up at `p.WaitForExit();`.

What could i be doing wrong?

```
 using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "ffmpeg -i \""+ musicFile +"\" -i  \""+  albumInfo.Image.Uri.ToString() +"\" -map 0:a -map 1 -codec copy -metadata:s:v title=\"Album cover\" -metadata:s:v comment=\"Cover (front)\" -disposition:v attached_pic \"" + directoryFile + "\\" + title + " - " + artist + "." + formatName + "\"";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: Does the command window ever close? This is waiting for the command shell to exit, and perhaps it never does.

Comment: WaitForExit(); Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit. close your cmd

Comment: You don't need `cmd.exe` to launch `ffmpeg`. That's just adding extra (pointless) steps, and considering you're missing /c, quite possibly causing you issues.

Comment: Because you set `RedirectStandardOutput` is true. You must read to end `OutputStream` first.

Answer (score 1):

You are not exiting after running the command. AFAIK, there is no exit flag in `ffmpeg` so I would make use of standard commands here.

Try doing something like this:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "ffmpeg -i \""+ musicFile +"\" -i  \""+  albumInfo.Image.Uri.ToString() +"\" -map 0:a -map 1 -codec copy -metadata:s:v title=\"Album cover\" -metadata:s:v comment=\"Cover (front)\" -disposition:v attached_pic \"" + directoryFile + "\\" + title + " - " + artist + "." + formatName + "\" & exit /b";
```

This would exit the command prompt as soon as `ffmpeg` is done. You might want to think about capturing the output of command before exit.

An alternative could also be to run the command directly without using command prompt since Process class can run the executables. You can get the path of `ffmpeg` executable and use that directly. Like this:

```
Process.Start("[full path of ffmpeg.exe here]", "-i \""+ musicFile +"\" -i  \""+  albumInfo.Image.Uri.ToString() +"\" -map 0:a -map 1 -codec copy -metadata:s:v title=\"Album cover\" -metadata:s:v comment=\"Cover (front)\" -disposition:v attached_pic \"" + directoryFile + "\\" + title + " - " + artist + "." + formatName + "\"";
```

Comment: Or OP could just not use cmd.exe at all then they wouldn't need something like `& exit /b`.